# Is quantum logic producing interesting/different mathematics?

Tags: logic

Is quantum logic producing interesting/different mathematics?

Is it different from the intuitionist approach to mathematics? How?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Quantum logic is a branch of mathematics, and it is different from other branches (that's why it has its own name), so in that sense, it is certainly producing interesting and different mathematics.

Comment: Why would you expect quantum logic to be the same as intuitionism?

Comment: @Qiaochu I was under the impression that if you change the laws of logic, a lot of proofs become invalid, and that makes different mathematics.

@Jim From the little I know, quantum logic talks about prepositions that neither have true nor false value, which reminds me of the intuitionist approach.

Comment: I don't think people use quantum logic that way, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

There is an approach to quantum logic where you get topoi with quantum logic. An elementary topos is sometimes regarded as a "place" where you can do mathematics, but where classical logic doesn't necessarily apply. Thus you get a different sort of mathematics.

I know very little about these quantum topoi, so I cannot detail in what way their mathematics differ from the classical one. But I think the two articles referenced in the below PlanetMath articles may (or may not - I haven't read them) answer your question.

- https://planetmath.org/quantumlogictoposes
- https://web.archive.org/web/20111128084313/http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/QuantumStateSpace.html